# How to force caching of 10mb+ images so they never get reloaded?

Tags: html, http, web

I have a site which has 10mb+ of images (1000+ pngs) that have to be loaded before it starts. My current approach is loading every image in a hidden tag. How can I ensure that a client that accesses the site once/month, for example, will never have to download it all again?

Answer (score 2):

No way. Client may have cache disabled, or he clears it every single minute

Comment: Can I signal it, at least? Otherwise how 2d games using html5 would be feasible at all?

Comment: I don't see what HTML5 games have to do with anything.

Comment: It's a HTML5 game in question which has 10mg+ of images used as item/character/map sprites. I'm asking if I have to make my clients download that whole array of sprites everytime they want to play?

Comment: You can tell the client that it should cache the images, but if the user *chooses* to clear their cache, there's nothing you can do. You can't force people to store files they don't want to keep. But if someone chooses to do it, I don't think they complain that they aren't cached anymore.

Comment: Sure, but they certainly won't chose it. So under normal conditions can I keep the whole array of sprites stored there and not have them to load before every playing session? I'm really worried now.

Comment: Browser will do stuff, you don't have to worry about it

Answer (score 1):

Compressed textures/generated textures/reused textures are how you should do it. You can't cache 10mb of images for a month reliably. If you need it for the game, then simply have a loading bar beforehand.

Comment: What size could I expect from the compression of 10mb of very different sprites?

Comment: Some examples, break the background down into seamless tiles and repeat it, reduce color depth, change format. It all depends on the files and what you do to them. As it is, 10mb isn't excessive to download for a game, I wouldn't be mad.

Comment: But every single time? I can't reduce it anymore, I'm already using tile based terrain. The 10mb worth of images are of actually different items, trees, creatures, montains and so on, the thing is huge :/

Comment: It's not that bad, less than what you would use watching a youtube video repeatedly

Comment: Dunno where you or the target audience live, but around here the average internet connection is about 30 mbps -- it'll take about 3 seconds to download 10mb.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use an application cache. This means dealing with the page and its images as an application, with a cache manifest (.appcache file) listing them and the HTML document containing an `<html manifest="...">` tag. See e.g. [A Beginner's Guide to Using the Application Cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/).